# Cypress reporter results filename

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress, mochawesome

I have multiple spec files in integration folder.
All these files, I am scheduling to run using single command as

```
node_modules\.bin\cypres run --spec .\cypress\integration\*.spec.js --env configFile=configuration_file
```

I am using mochawsome reporter to generate result file. But I have a problem with output files.

Instead of having those json report files named as `mochawsone_xx`, I need the json files to be generated with their spec file names.

Is there a way in cypress to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress allows you to pass in reporter options via command line. [Check out the documentation.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters#Reporter-Options) You can also set it in your config, if required.

In your case, it would look something like this from the command line:

```
node_modules\.bin\cypres run --spec .\cypress\integration\*.spec.js --env configFile=configuration_file --reporter-options="reportFilename=myCustomName"
```

Comment: But this will assign static name to all `N` number of spec files, I need a way to name the reporter output file as my spec filename.